# Evaluating a limit I

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Consider the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[ \frac{(x+a)^{x+1}}{(x+b)^{x}} - \frac{(x+a-n)^{x+1-n}}{(x+b-n)^{x-n}} \right].
\end{align}
It is speculated that the resulting value is exponential in nature. What are some processes to demonstrate this speculation?

Comment: Have you tried [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz-Cesaro_theorem) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's find asymptotics of
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x+a)^{x+1}}{(x+b)^x}.
$$
Your limit is 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x) - f(x-n)).
$$
So,
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x+a)^{x+1}}{(x+b)^x} = (x+a) \frac{x^x \left(1+\frac ax\right)^x}{x^x \left(1+\frac bx\right)^x} = (x+a)\left(e^{a-b} + \frac12e^{a-b}(b^2-a^2)\frac1x + o\left(\frac1x\right)\right)
$$
and your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} (f(x) - f(x-n)) = ne^{a-b}.
$$